# ViewPager for screen slides from right to left

Tags: android, android-viewpager, right-to-left

I am using ViewPager for screen slide it works fine for language's script from left to right but for Arabic script which is actually right to left is not feasible

can i swipe pages of viewpager in reverse order?

Comment: You want to set slider from right to left instead of left to right, is this what you are asking?

Comment: this worked with me very good >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/59389545/11365488

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPagerSize);
```

and this will make user swipe right to left

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't understand when to put this code. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

At the time of this post, ViewPager still doesn't handle RTL correctly. Here's a a workaround when using TabLayout:

1. Set `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` in the TabLaout XML, so it will
   always display left-to-right.
2. Before you call `setupWithViewPager(viewPager)`, check if running in RTL, and if so, reverse the order of the tabs, and start with the last tab:

   ```
   if (MyApp.isRTL()) {
       Collections.reverse(pgAdapter.fragmentList);
       viewPager.setCurrentItem(pgAdapter.getCount() - 1);
   }
   ```

RTL can be checked using the following code:

```
public static boolean isRTL() {
    final int directionality = Character.getDirectionality(
            Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName().charAt(0));
    return directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT ||
            directionality == Character.DIRECTIONALITY_RIGHT_TO_LEFT_ARABIC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this but it is not professional

Write this in xml for VeiwPager
      `android:rotationY="180"`
and also in veiw_item
        `android:rotationY="180"`..