# Android change default direction swipe of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

by default `ViewPager` swipe direction is left to right to view other tabs with content, now i like to change this direction to right to left.

my `FragmentPagerAdapter` class :

```
public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return MainCategoryListFragment.newInstance(2);
            case 1:
                return ChildFragment.newInstance(1);
            case 2:
                return ParentFragment.newInstance(0);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title = "";
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                title =  "one";
                break;
            case 1:
                title =  "two";
                break;
            case 2:
                title =  "tree";
                break;
        }
        return title;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781944/how-to-make-my-viewpager-swipe-from-right-to-left

Comment: isn't it enough to start showing the last page instead of the first one?

Answer (score 0):

**ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int pageIndex, boolean isSmoothScroll);**

pageIndex is total page count.  by doing this user will be forced to swipe from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

Copy-pasted answer from [here](http://blog.dision.co/2016/01/19/change-viewpager-swipe-direction-easily/)

> I faced the same problem month ago but I think I found a great
>   solution.
>
> 1) Change your TabLayout direction to ltr in xml:
>
> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
>     android:id="@+id/tl_activity_main"
>     android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_activity_main"
>     android:layoutDirection="ltr"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     style="@style/DisionTabLayout" />
> ```
>
> 2) Create custom adapter for ViewPager and override methods
>   getItem(int position) and getPageTitle(int position):
>
> ```
> @Override
> public Fragment getItem(int position) {
>     if (mIsRtlOrientation && mTabs != null && mTabs.length > 0) {
>         return mTabs[mTabs.length - position - 1].getFragment();
>     } else {
>         return mTabs[position].getFragment();
>     }
> }
>
> @Override
> public int getCount() {
>     return mTabs.length;
> }
>
> @Override
> public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
>     if (mIsRtlOrientation && mTabs != null && mTabs.length > 0) {
>         return mTabs[mTabs.length - position - 1].getTitle();
>     } else {
>         return mTabs[position].getTitle();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> 3) Set the adapter to ViewPager and then apply this ViewPager to
>   TabLayout.
>
> ```
> private void setAdapters() {
>     // initialize adapter
>     mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mTabs, true);
>     // set adapter to ViewPager
>     vp.setAdapter(mTabsAdapter);
>     // set ViewPager to TabLayout
>     tl.setupWithViewPager(vp);
>     // if RTL orientation, go to last item
>     vp.setCurrentItem(vp.getAdapter().getCount() - 1, false);
> }
> ```
>
> 4) I created a blog post which contains more details and full code -
>   [here](http://blog.dision.co/2016/01/19/change-viewpager-swipe-direction-easily/)