# how to make my viewpager swipe from right to left (android)

Tags: android, android-viewpager

i created a function to rotate the view pager to make it swipe from right to left, as the following:

```
    public void rotateViews(View view){
        view.setRotationY(180);
    }
```

but the internal views will be rotated so i rotate them too, so in this case i can start from right to left, is there is a better way to do.

some people says to use viewPager.setCurrentItem() but this will not work in my case, because i want to start from the first position not the last one.

Comment: try this<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781944/how-to-make-my-viewpager-swipe-from-right-to-left>.

Comment: sorry that's not working in my case, because setCurrentItem() i have to put the last position of my viewer right?

what i want is when i swipe to (from right to left) the position will be incremented not decremented.

Answer (score 0):

try this its works set current page to the last page using this code

```
 viewPager.setCurrentItem().
```

Comment: if i used this that's mean i will start from the last page of the pager, right?