# My application uses fragments but i need left to right swipe rather right to left

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have done swiping pager view fragments but i need left to right swipe rather right to left, like when i click on index button it opens case 0 fragment from pageradapter and then i swipe left to right to move to another fragment. i have posted my code it allows me right to left swipe on screen

```
index1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Index.this , MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("fragment_index_key", 0);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    index2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Index.this , MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("fragment_index_key", 1);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

these are 2 buttons on which fragments are opened

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
ViewPager viewpager ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewpager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
    PagerAdapter padapter  = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewpager.setAdapter(padapter);
    viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    int index = getIntent().getIntExtra("fragment_index_key", 0); // 0 is default value
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(index);
}
```

}

this is my main activity

```
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch(position)
    {
        case 0 :
            return new Page1();

        case 1 :
            return new Page2() ;

        case 2 :
            //return new Page3();

        default :
            break ;
     }
     return null ;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2 ;
}
```

}

this is pager adapter

Comment: What you mean by swipe ? `ViewPager` works on touch gesture.

Comment: i thing using `TabView` u can move right to left and left to right swiping

Answer (score 0):

You can set the fragment in opposite direction you get solution in this [how to make my viewpager swipe from right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781944/how-to-make-my-viewpager-swipe-from-right-to-left)