# how to reverse the direction of PagerAdapter to left to right order?

Tags: android, android-studio

MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.androidbegin.viewpagertutorial;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter adapter;
    String[] rank;
    String[] country;
    String[] population;
    int[] flag;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from viewpager_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_main);

        // Generate sample data
        rank = new String[] { "1", "2", "3"};

        country = new String[] { "China", "India", "United States",
        };

        population = new String[] { "1,354,040,000", "1,210,193,422",
                "315,761,000"};

        flag = new int[] { R.drawable.page001, R.drawable.page002,
                R.drawable.page003};

        // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, rank, country, population, flag);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter code:

```
package com.androidbegin.viewpagertutorial;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    String[] rank;
    String[] country;
    String[] population;
    int[] flag;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] rank, String[] country,
                            String[] population, int[] flag) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.country = country;
        this.population = population;
        this.flag = flag;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {return rank.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView txtrank;
        TextView txtcountry;
        TextView txtpopulation;
        ImageView imgflag;


        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
                false);


        // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
        imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
        // Capture position and set to the ImageView
        imgflag.setImageResource(flag[position]);

        // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

    }
}
```

What do I need to change in either of the two classes so that it starts on the last image instead of the first (right to left)?

the behavior i want is that after the first image is displayed, is that you can't swipe to the left.

i searched a lot for clever way to implement this but no results..
thanks in advance.

Comment: take look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489723/how-to-reverse-the-direction-of-viewpager-to-left-to-right-order

Comment: I already did but I don't know how to