# How to use fragment with Viewpager for Swipe pages

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I got doubt regarding Viewpager and Fragment .I want to create swipe view for that i need  fragment classes with Viewpager .how could i implement such thing!!

i searched through net got something like this using viewpager!!

```
   public class ViewPagerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);

        // initialsie the pager
        this.initialisePaging();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the fragments to be paged
     */
    private void initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment0.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment1.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment2.class.getName()));
        this.mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

Manifest File:

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="slider.example.ViewPagerFragmentActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="slider.example.Fragment0" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="slider.example.Fragment1" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="slider.example.Fragment2" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity android:name=".MyPagerAdapter"></activity>
    </application>
```

Error:

```
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{slider.example/slider.example.ViewPagerFragmentActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: slider.example.ViewPagerFragmentActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/slider.example-2.apk]
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: slider.example.ViewPagerFragmentActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/slider.example-2.apk]
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468):  ... 11 more
```

Could anybody guide me @thanks !!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180539/working-with-viewpager-and-fragments

Comment: @RajeshCP thanks but i need to use dynamic pages how could i do that

Comment: You can use pagerAdapter for that, each time the page changes provide the Fragment what you want.

Answer (score 5):

I Found this tutorial realy clear and helpful for creating a Fragment ViewPager:

http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/android-tabs-viewpager-swipe-able-tabs-ftw/

Check it out, in addiotion please refer to here as well:

http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.co.il/2012/10/viewpager-example-in-android.html
http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/
http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-circle-style-example/

**ViewPager without tabs:**

http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/

UPDATE:

First of all remove this part:

```
<activity android:name="slider.example.Fragment0" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity android:name="slider.example.Fragment1" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity android:name="slider.example.Fragment2" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity android:name=".MyPagerAdapter"></activity>
```

Not the Fragments or the Adapter are not activities and you shouldn't write them into the manifest file.

and try to change this part:

```
<activity android:name="slider.example.ViewPagerFragmentActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

To this:

```
<activity android:name=".ViewPagerFragmentActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks but i need without Tabs..how could i do that!!

Comment: post your ViewPagerFragmentActivity code and the manifest file code.

Comment: Emil Adz could you help me out!!

Answer (score 1):

Visit '[Replacing a fragment in a view pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649749/replacing-a-fragment-in-a-view-pager/15652478#15652478)', For view pager transactions. And when you are looking to study for fragments then visit-'http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle'

Comment: thanks i am getting error using that!!04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 13:22:39.804: E/AndroidRuntime(468): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{slider.example/slider.example.ViewPagerFragmentActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: slider.example.ViewPagerFragmentActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/slider.example-2.apk]

Comment: Sino Raj could you help me out!!

Comment: <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="slider.example.ViewPagerFragmentActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

Comment: not add all classes in your activity, and then remember all classes are not activity. Where u use fragments as activity, so please study about Activity and what that differs from fragments,adapter classes and so on

Comment: Add one fragment,adapter and view pager on layout in your post/question

Comment: Sino Raj i have a doubt can we display the middle fragment first!!

Comment: Their is any error after run ur application?, when u want to show a page on view pager with ur on position then initialize the view pager, then write viewPagerName.setCurrentItem(position);

Comment: viewPagerName.setCurrentItem(position); Using this can i set the middle fragment as mainview and onswipe left first fragment and on swipe right third frag will show

Comment: viewPagerName.setCurrentItem(1);, when u fine with my answer, then plz upvote, and tick as correct answer.

Comment: Sino Raj  k.. fine..let me check

Comment: @ Sino Raj no i didn't get